# Window.scroll too slow? Or is this something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, sticky

So I almost never have to ask questions, this is my first one.  But I only found one post with a similar issue.  (I couldn't find a way incorporate that answer)

I'm trying to accomplish an iOS style list with my project where the header of one item becomes absolute on the bottom of the previous item while the header of the current item becomes fixed.

I have this working, but it's finicky...   In my example, I have the transition between items 1 and 2 working perfectly EVERY TIME.  However, the transition between 1 and the initial header does not work unless you scroll up very slowly (scrolling down always works).

I believe the issue here is that Window.Scroll can't process fast enough, so for instance .scrollTop() will skip from say 300 to 200 skipping 250, and hence returning FALSE in the if statement.

At this point I'm out of ideas to get this working, maybe some of the JS Wizards on here will know something I don't?

https://jsfiddle.net/ouu6hxuh/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var index = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / $(window).height()) + 1;
    var top = ($("section").height() * index) - $(window).scrollTop();
    if (index > 1) {
        $(".menu").addClass('menu-fixed');
    } else {
        $(".menu").removeClass('menu-fixed');
    }

    if (top > 52 && top < $("section").height()) {
        $("#title" + (index - 1)).css({
            "position": "fixed",
                "width": "calc(100% - 40px)",
                "top": "0",
                "left": "40px"
        });
    } else if (top < 52) {
        $("#title" + (index - 1)).css({
            "position": "absolute",
                "width": "100%",
                "top": "calc(100% - 52px)",
                "left": "0px"
        });
    } else if (top == $("section").height()) {
        $("#title" + (index - 1)).css({
            "position": "absolute",
                "width": "100%",
                "top": "0",
                "left": "0px"
        });
    }
});
});
```

//REVISION

I've incorporated the setTimeout() into the function set at 100ms intervals, but I'm still having the same issue.

//REVISION 2

I've replaced the setTimeout() with requestAnimationFrame() to no avail.
https://jsfiddle.net/ouu6hxuh/2/

Comment: The "scroll" event is fired very aggressively by browsers; the tiniest user activity causes an event to be fired. Your code is doing rather a lot of DOM lookups and manipulation, so the browser will be running that code very frequently. Generally it's good to introduce a time-sensitive buffer of some sort to keep updates down to 10 or so per second.

Comment: @peter Alright, would I use something like setTimeout()?  I thought that by limiting the time it would cause it to skip even worse, kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: Use requestAnimationFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @RichBradshaw how would I use that?  I'm still a bit confused, what does the animation have to do with scrolling?

Comment: Scrolling is an animation when you think about it. Use it in place of setTimeout  but without a time parameter. This tells the browser to do your work the next time it can draw a new frame, rather than on every scroll event.

Comment: @RichBradshaw any other ideas?  Am I doing something wrong?